# Pass Ruby 2 keyword arguments without specifying them explicitly

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

How I can pass the keyword arguments to a call to another method in my code without specifying each of them.

Consider the following method with the new first-class support for kwargs:

```
def foo(obj, bar: 'a', baz: 'b')
  another_method(bar, baz)
end
```

Consider the old Ruby options hash syntax:

```
def foo(obj, options = {})
  another_method(options)
end
```

I want to pass the keyword arguments without specifying each of them explicitly as with the case of the old options hash syntax. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the double-splat operator:

```
def a(q: '1', w: '2')
  p q
  p w
end

def b(**options)
  a(options)
end

b
# => 1
# => 2

b(q: '3', w: '4')
# => 3
# => 4
```

Comment: Does that answer the OP? I want to call another method with the arguments without explicitly specifying them inside the original method, not a way to create another method that accepts whatever args.

Comment: Why not? The method don't accepts any args. In my example, if you try `b(x: '1')` you will get `unknown keyword: x`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the existence of the double splat operator. I couldn't find information about how to do this anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Keyword arguments work similarly to your "old Ruby options hash syntax". A hash's keys will substitute as keywords and their values as arguments. This should work fine:

```
def foo(obj, bar: 'a', baz: 'b')
  another_method(bar, baz)
end

arg_hash = { bar: 'alt bar', baz: 'alt baz' }

foo(Object.new, arg_hash)
```

#### Some things to be aware of

If your hash keys are strings, such as `{ 'bar' => 'alt bar', 'baz' => 'alt baz' }`, this won't work. You'll get an `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)` error. This is easy enough to fix in Rails by calling `.symbolize_keys` on the hash. If you're not in Rails, you'll have to convert the keys manually or reimplement that method.

Also, in Rails, a HashWithIndifferentAccess (such as the `params` hash in a controller), although it has both strings and symbols for keys, can't be used in this way. If you pass `params`, it will look at the string keys instead and you'll get the same error as above. I'm not sure why this is the case, but my guess it's because the params hash starts with strings and adds symbols so the symbols are secondary and not the default. Total guess on that though.